# How to save a read-only file in Geany?

Tags: geany

When edit a read-only file by Geany, I can't save the file.

Is there some plug-in support to change the file's mode then save it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might could use the save as function as save it under new name + rename the old one. Change permissions is not yet supported.